# How to write this simple code in a reactive way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new to project reactor and I have some difficulties to find a clean solution for the following use case.

**My use case:**

I want to save a new object in the database. If the object is already in the database I want to send an error response if not I want to save it and return the saved object to the client.

**In a blocking web mvc application the code would look like this:**

```
    @PostMapping("/cards")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCard(@RequestBody Card card) {
        Card c = repo.findOneByWord(card.getWord());

        if(c == null) {
            Card savedCard = repo.save(card);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(savedCard);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("Card already exists");
    }
```

**My non-blocking webflux approach:**

```
@PostMapping("/cards")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> addCard(@RequestBody Card card) {

    return repo.findOneByWord(card.getWord())
            .map(c -> {
                return new Card();
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> repo.save(card)))
            .map(c -> {
                if (c.getWord() == null) {
                    return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("Card already exists.");
                }

                return ResponseEntity.ok(c);
            });
}
```

The code is working fine but the readability is bad and it feels more like a workaround ...

Any suggestion on how I can make this more clean / readable?

Comment: What does `findOneByWord` return in the second example and what's the point of the first `map`? Must be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite that code in the following way:

```
@PostMapping("/cards")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> addCard(@RequestBody Card card) {

    return repo.findOneByWord(card.getWord())                     // (1)

               .map(c ->                                          // (2)
                   ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity()           // (2.1)
                                 .body("Card already exists.")    //
               )                                                  // 

               .switchIfEmpty(                                    // (3)
                   repo.save(card)                                // (3.1)
                       .map(c -> ResponseEntity.ok(c)             // (3.2)
               );                                                 //
}
```

1. Execution of the database query which may return `Mono` with value or empty response.
2. Only in case of returned value, the subsequent `.map` will be executed so we will map card to 422 response
3. Otherwise, in the case when there is no such cart in DB, the `.map` function will be skipped, so the publisher passed to `.switchIfEmpty` will be subscribed. *Note*, it is not necessary to wrap creation of the fallback `Mono` (points 3.1) into `Mono.defer` since actual element's storing will happen only in case of subscribing to the given stream. Hence, since that execution happens only when the `swithIfEmpty` will be handled, we may reduce unnecessary wrapping. Finally, at point (3.2) the result will be mapped to the 200 response with the stored `Card` object.